# bash tab-completion list below prompt

Tags: bash, tab-completion

Whenever I use tab-completion, the list of possibilities is displayed and the prompt is duplicated below (`|` indicates the final cursor position):

```
$ vim ~/.<TAB>
./    ../    .bashrc    .vimrc
$ vim ~/.|
```

I would like the following, zsh-like behavior:

```
$ vim ~/.<TAB>|
./    ../    .bashrc    .vimrc
```

That is, show the suggestions *below the old prompt*.
Old suggestions should be overwritten or vanish once I'm done completing instead of cluttering my screen.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

While `bash` does not have a perfect match for the `zsh` completion menu, you can cut down on screen clutter with `menu-complete` bindings in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind '\C-n:menu-complete'
bind '\C-p:menu-complete-previous'
```

These bindings cycle through completions on the commmand line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (without showing the complete list). Your system may already have these keys bound; to check:

```
bind -p | grep menu-complete
```